# How to return the same DNS records for all domains?

Tags: dns

I have a random number of domains (`sub.client1.example`, `sub.client2.example`, etc.) that I ask my clients to delegate to my name servers through a NS record.

The configuration for every delegated domain should be exactly the same (a CNAME to a fixed domain that we own and a record for SSL validation).

How to configure my DNS servers to accept requests for any domain name and return the correct configuration for it? Is there a hosted service like Route53 or DynDNS that would provide vanity name servers with support for that use case?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying with which nameservers.

With most of them, like Bind, you can write your zonefile in such a way that the domain name itself does not appear in the labels.
Basically you write `www CNAME www.whatever.example` and the missing dot at the end of `www` forces the nameserver to automatically add the domain name.

So with a zonefile written like that, you can configure your nameserver for all domain names it should be authoritative on and use that same exact zonefile.

This is one among many other options.
To be a little more on-topic for this programming Q&A website you could also:

- use a nameserver that allows to use as source, instead of a static text file, content of a database (that some program of yours could fill in) or even directly a program that will get called to reply to each DNS packet
- use some templating mechanism and some program to build all zonefile text files from other sources (like a database) before starting the nameserver.

Note that the first case with a "generic" zonefile text file is by far the easiest so that should be your first try.

Of course various providers on line could give you the same features more or less, starting with your registrar that could give you DNS hosting also. But it is also achievable by yourself if you agree to install and maintain a nameserver.

Also, you do not need any vanity server to do all of that, and I recommend you to just not follow that leads as it will not give you any kind of benefit.